# updating, printing, etc, individual values in hash that has multiple values per key

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to build some logic for solving Coudal's "Whose Fish?" puzzle. There may be a better way to store and process things, but right now I am using five hashes with five keys which each have five values, as that follows along with the puzzle.

```
 House1 = {"color"=>["red","grn","blu",...etc],
            "pet" =>["horse","bird","cat",...etc],
            ...etc }
```

Is there a way to access the values here numerically? For example, I want to update only the value "bird" to be something else. Pet is the second key, bird is the second value.

I want to be able to do things like (not actual code here, sorry)

```
 Go find key 2, value 2, and replace value 2 with "X"
 Go find key 2, value 2, and compare value 2 with "Y"
 Go find key 2, value 2, and print value 2 on the screen
```

Doing this is completely straightforward with single values, but I was not able to find any discussion of this here. Certainly, I can set the hashes up like this-

```
 house1 = { "col1"=>"red","col2"=>"grn" ... "pet1"=>"horse", ... etc}
```

But that's a lot less easy to look at and think about.

Comment: Hi- sorry, yes, I am working through this slowly, it's turning out to be a far larger can of worms than I expected... I feel like all three messages helped me, but, I guess I will just select the person who responded first. Thanks again to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways come to mind:

```
house1 # => {"color"=>["red", "grn", "blu"], "pet"=>["horse", "bird", "cat"]}
house1_ary = house1.to_a
house1_ary[1] # => ["pet", ["horse", "bird", "cat"]]
house1_ary[1][1] # => ["horse", "bird", "cat"]
house1_ary[1][1][1] # => "bird"
house1_ary[1][1][1] = 'octochicken'
house1_ary # => [["color", ["red", "grn", "blu"]], ["pet", ["horse", "octochicken", "cat"]]]
```

Converting back to a hash is easy. For Ruby 2.0+:

```
house1_ary.to_h # => {"color"=>["red", "grn", "blu"], "pet"=>["horse", "octochicken", "cat"]}
```

Otherwise:

```
Hash[house1_ary] # => {"color"=>["red", "grn", "blu"], "pet"=>["horse", "octochicken", "cat"]}
```

Or:

```
Hash[*house1_ary.flatten(1)] # => {"color"=>["red", "grn", "blu"], "pet"=>["horse", "octochicken", "cat"]}
```

You *could* use an integer for the key, which would allow you to do what you're saying, while keeping everything in a hash. It's easy to create:

```
house1 = {
  "color"=>["red","grn","blu"],
  "pet" =>["horse","bird","cat"],
}

house1_by_int = (0..(house1.size - 1)).to_a.zip(house1.values).to_h
# => {0=>["red", "grn", "blu"], 1=>["horse", "bird", "cat"]}

house1_by_int[1] # => ["horse", "bird", "cat"]
house1_by_int[1][1] # => "bird"
house1_by_int[1][1] = 'octochicken'
house1_by_int # => {0=>["red", "grn", "blu"], 1=>["horse", "octochicken", "cat"]}
```

Either way, you'll also be updating the values in the original `house1` also, because the values will point to the same arrays:

```
house1 # => {"color"=>["red", "grn", "blu"], "pet"=>["horse", "octochicken", "cat"]}
```

---

> No reason I can't use numerals for key values.. 1 for house and 2 for pet, etc.

Well, yes there could be. We use hashes because the key/value pair is more easily remembered and understood, which, as the data grows, helps reduce maintenance problems.

Another way to deal with the problem is to create a little table to map between the integer values and the actual names of the keys:

```
key_map = Hash[[*(0..(house1.size - 1))].zip(house1.keys)]
# => {0=>"color", 1=>"pet"}

house1[key_map[1]] # => ["horse", "bird", "cat"]
house1[key_map[1]][1] = 'octochicken'
house1 # => {"color"=>["red", "grn", "blu"], "pet"=>["horse", "octochicken", "cat"]}
```

Doing that preserves the original hash, while allowing you flexibility in how you address the hash's elements, and it looks and works similar to using array indexing.

Comment: Ha. Looks like I had better update from 1.9.3... to_h not part of my install. thank you for the help, I will give this a spin!

Comment: It's easy to do with < v2.0. I'll add it.

Comment: Oh- I get it now. No reason I can't use numerals for key values.. 1 for house and 2 for pet, etc. Very good. Thank you! I will try it out here shortly.

Comment: The reason you *don't* want to use numbers is because, as the data grows, it's harder to remember what the numbers stand for, which becomes a code-maintenance problem. Instead, we use the strings in the keys. I'll add some code to show how you *could* work around this.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby v1.9, the elements of hashes maintain their order, but you generally should think of the key-value pairs as being unordered.  That is, it is not good programming practice to extract or change a key-value pair based on its offset in the hash.

You could do the three things you want to do like this:

Let:

```
h = {"color"=>["red","grn","blu"],
     "pet"  =>["horse","bird","cat"],
     "grub" =>["pancakes", "waffles", "donuts"]}
```

*Go find key 2, value 2, and replace value 2 with "X"*

I'd like to change this to:

*Replace `h["pet"][1]` with the value `"X"`*

```
def replace(h, key, offset, replacement)
  h[key][offset] = replacement
end

replace(h, "pet", 1, "X")
  #=> "X"
h
  #=> {"color"=>["red", "grn", "blu"],
  #    "pet"  =>["horse", "X", "cat"],
  #    "grub" =>["pancakes", "waffles", "donuts"]}
```

*Go find key 2, value 2, and compare value 2 with "Y"*

*Go find key 2, value 2, and print value 2 on the screen*

*Change these to:*

*Compare `h["pet"][1]` with the value `"Y"`*

*Print `h["pet"][1]`*

```
def extract(h, key, offset)
  h[key][offset]
end

extract(h, "pet", 1) == "Y"
  #=> false
puts extract(h, "pet", 1)
  # bird
```

Comment: I like the def replace(h, key, offset, replacement), that may work too. Thank you, I am learning a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your example, disregard wrong chosen data type:

```
House1 = {"color"=>["red","grn","blu"],
          "pet"  =>["horse","bird","cat"]}

# singleton method to update value at given index(es)    
def House1.update_at(key_ix, val_ix, val)
  entries[key_ix][1][val_ix] = val
  self
end

p House1.update_at 1, 1, 'xxx'
# {"color"=>["red", "grn", "blu"], "pet"=>["horse", "xxx", "cat"]}
```

btw. names of variables should begin with a lowercase character

Comment: Oh, these are all great options- thank you for the help.

Comment: @WillVonWizzlepig Thou art welcome ;) Hope my solution looks brief and clean. Just a note - choosing key-based `Hash` class to access its elements with indexes instead of keys is a bit awkward. I'd try to write own class in such situations as it's very easy and straightforward in Ruby and offers a great comfort for further demands.